# Make images draggable over canvas in Android

Tags: android, zooming, scale, drag

I am new at here. I want to know a bit about how can I make one image drag gable over other. I have used [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library from github but not finding the solution. Up until now while searching on Google, I have managed to play with this code. But not able to use it in the desired way. Also, I have used `RelativeLayout` and not able to get the `ImageView` one over the other on selection. I am in a complete mess right now, I need help from someone.

Also, I want to make one image zoomable, draggable, and rotatable over the other image in that canvas but nothing works smoothly. The code below makes the images zoomable and draggable, but it's not smooth.

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        float scale;

        dumpEvent(event);

        // Handle touch events here...

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // first finger down only

                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                mode = DRAG;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                mode = NONE;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                if (oldDist > 5f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:


                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
                            - start.y); /*
                                     * create the transformation in the matrix
                                     * of points
                                     */
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    // pinch zooming
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                    if (newDist > 5f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    /*
                     * setting the scaling of the matrix...if scale > 1 means
                     * zoom in...if scale < 1 means zoom out
                     */
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
//        quadrantTouched[getQuadrant(event.getX() - (dialerWidth / 2), dialerHeight - event.getY() - (dialerHeight / 2))] = true;

//        this.view.onTouchEvent(event);
        view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

        return true;
    }

    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }


    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        String names[] = {"DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
                "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?"};
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
                || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
            sb.append("(pid ").append(
                    action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
            sb.append(")");
        }

        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
            sb.append("#").append(i);
            sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
            sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
            sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
            if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
        }

        sb.append("]");
        Log.d("Touch Event", sb.toString());
    }
```